# Google App Script to Group Row data in sheet based on email column

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, mapping

I have google sheet with several projects. The sheet also has names of project leaders that manage these projects. One project leaders can manage up to 5 projects at a go. The sheet looks like this.

[image]

I would like to group each row data by column F (email) and send one email to each project lead on the projects they are managing, say for instance **Tim Curry** will receive a table listing only the projects he leads.  My code below is not adequate to accomplish this task and I will appreciate help in modifying it to group the data and send it as HTML.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows =  12;   // Number of rows to process                     
 
  
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 12)  
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var emails = data.map(function (e) { 
    return e[5]; 
  })
  var uniqueEmails = [...new Set(emails)];
  
  for (var j = 0; j < uniqueEmails.length; j++) {
    var subject = "";
    var body = "Please see if your project is on course, if not foward this email to PMS admin"
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][5] == uniqueEmails[j]){
        var row = data[i];
        var projectnumber = row[0];
        var startdate = row[1];
        var enddate = row[2];
        var projectname = row[3];
        var projectlead= row[4];
        var email= row[5];
        
        
        var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
        var tableRangeValues=sheet.getRange(2,1, lr-1,6).getDisplayValues();
        
        var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Notify") 
        htmlTemplate.projectnumber = projectnumber;
        htmlTemplate.startdate= startdate;
        htmlTemplate.enddate= enddate;
        htmlTemplate.projectname= projectname;
        htmlTemplate.projectlead=projectlead;
        htmlTemplate.email=email;
        var htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
        
        if (enddate instanceof Date && enddate.getTime()>= new Date(07/14/20).getTime()) {   
         var emailSent = row[6];           
          if (emailSent != "Y") {
            subject += "Action Required - Project End"; 
          }
        }
        
      }
    }
    if(subject.length > 0){
      
                MailApp.sendEmail({
                to: uniqueEmails[j], 
                cc: "example@gmail.com",
                subject: subject, 
                body: body
              }); 
    }
  }
}
```

**Notify** HTML table Code:

```
 <thead>
<tr>
<th><?=projectnumber?></th>
<th><?=startdate?></th>
<th><?=enddate?></th>
<th><?=projectname?></th>
<th><?=projectlead?></th>
<th><?=email?></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?tableRangeValues.forEach(r=>{?>
<tr>
<td><?=r[0]?></td>
<td><?=r[1]?></td>
<td><?=r[2]?></td>
<td><?=r[3]?></td>
<td><?=r[4]?></td>
<td><?=r[5]?></td>
</tr>
<?})?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use [... new Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to retrieve unique emails from the sheet and concatenate the email contents for the rows that correspond to each unique email

**Sample:**

```js
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows =  12;   // Number of rows to process                     
  //  var numItems = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(startRow,1 numRows, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  // var numRows = numItems[0]
  
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 11)  
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var emails = data.map(function (e) { 
    return e[5]; 
  })
  var uniqueEmails = [...new Set(emails)];
  
  for (var j = 0; j < uniqueEmails.length; j++) {
    var subject = "";
    var body = "Please see if your project is on course, if not foward this email to PMS admin"
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][5] == uniqueEmails[j]){
        var row = data[i];
        var projectnumber = row[0];
        var startdate = row[1];
        var enddate = row[2];
        var projectname = row[3];
        var projectlead= row[4];
        var email= row[5];
        if (enddate instanceof Date && enddate.getTime()>= new Date(07/14/20).getTime()) {   
         var emailSent = row[6];           
          if (emailSent != "Y") {
            subject += "Action Required - Project: " + projectname + " " + projectnumber + " " ; 
          }
        }
        
      }
    }
    if(subject.length > 0){
      
                 MailApp.sendEmail({
                to: uniqueEmails[j], 
                cc: "admin@example.com",
                subject: subject, 
                body: body
              }); 
    }
  }
}
```

### UPDATE

If you want to group the rows e.g. to pass them together to a loop in the html template, you can use the Javascript function [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

**Sample**

*Code.gs*

```js
var tableRangeValues;

function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows =  12;   // Number of rows to process                       
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 12)  
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var emails = data.map(function (e) { 
    return e[5]; 
  })
  var uniqueEmails = [...new Set(emails)];  
  for (var j = 0; j < uniqueEmails.length; j++) {
    var subject = "Action Required - Project End";
    var body = "Please see if your project is on course, if not foward this email to PMS admin";
    
    tableRangeValues = data.filter(function(row){return (row[5] == uniqueEmails[j]);});
    var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Notify") ;
    var htmlForEmail = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
    body += htmlForEmail;
    
    if(filteredData.length > 0){
      Logger.log("body: " + body);  
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: uniqueEmails[j], 
        cc: "example@gmail.com",
        subject: subject, 
        htmlBody: body
      }); 
    }
  }
}
```

*Notify.html*

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <thead>

</thead>
<tbody>
<?tableRangeValues.forEach(r=>{?>
<tr>
<td><?=r[0]?></td>
<td><?=r[1]?></td>
<td><?=r[2]?></td>
<td><?=r[3]?></td>
<td><?=r[4]?></td>
<td><?=r[5]?></td>
</tr>
<?})?>
</tbody>
</table>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Note that you need to declare `tableRangeValues` as a global variable if you want to use in the html template with scriptlets
- Note that if you want to send an email with an `htmlBody` you have to specify it as such within `MailApp.sendEmail()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding to my question.  I have edited my code in the question to reflect what I have now. I am trying to pass row values of the grouped emails values to html table to send via email, but every time I run into an error **tableRangeValues**. Could you kindly help me to see what am not doing right. Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually my intention was to have the row data of the same project leader put in one table and sent to their email. That is they should receive list of projects they manage. I am not sure. Am I am making sense?